# Script to create a static library from all .c file in my working directory

Tags: c, bash, shell, static-libraries

I am trying to write a script that create a static library call `libwork.a` in the working directory from all the `.c` files in the directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -c *.c | ar cr libwork.a *.o
```

But as I run my script, it only creates the object files. The `libwork.a` does not get created. I tried both sourcing and executing my script but it still only creates object files only.

Why is it not creating the archive?

Comment: Don't write a script.  Use make or cmake.

Comment: Why do you want to pipe the output of `gcc` into `ar`? You can just make 2 separate commands on 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are piping the messages printed by gcc (most surely none) to ar (which does not read anything). This is nonesense, ar should run after gcc.
2. The file listing generated by "*.o" is passed before "gcc" finished.

The solution is to remove that pipe and simply run the commands one after the other.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
gcc -c *.c
ar cr libwork.a *.o
```

Note the "-e". This tells the shell to abort if one of the commands fails, so if gcc fails ar will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Also, have a look at this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -c *.c
ar -rc libwork.a *.o
ranlib libwork.a
```